# How to place "&" in xml strings file in android studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-resources

I have my xml string file like this:

```
<string name="text1">ben & angie</string>
```

But it says I have an unescaped & .  How to escape it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Write:

```
<string name="text1">ben &amp; angie</string>
```

Here is a [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) to the xml spec how to escape characters.